# Probability both gates are closed?

Tags: probability

***I'm sorry the title is not the exact event I'm looking for. I tried to ask this exact question with the correct title but it wouldn't let me even though I deleted this one***

The probability that gate A is open is $0.7$ and the probability gate B is open is 0.4, and the probability at least one gate is open is $0.8$.

**LET**
$P(A)$ be the probability A is open, $P(B)$ represents B is open.

The question is: *Given that the first gate is open what's the probability the second gate is open?*
My guess is that $P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B )}{P(A)}$
where $P(A \cap B ) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cup B)=0.7+0.4-0.8=0.3$

So now I get:

$P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B )}{P(A)}=\frac{0.3}{0.7}$

Is this correct? The reason I thought I should do $\frac{P(A \cap B )}{P(A)}$ is because I want to know the likelihood of both being open **out of** how often A is open, hence the division?

Comment: This seems correct to me

Comment: @angryavian I'll take your word for it, over 700 posts in probability alone